Symmetry transformation exact meaning
In whatever text/review I happen to come across (like for example From Noether’s Theorem to Bremsstrahlung: A pedagogical introduction to
Large gauge transformations and Classical soft theorems, written by Noah Miller), the explanation for the Noether's theorem(s) starts in the following way:

If you have a symmetry transformation $\delta\phi_i=\epsilon \delta_{\text{sym}}\phi_i$ where $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal constant, then the action will change by the total derivative of some vector $J^{\mu}$.

My question is, why does the fact that a transformation is a symmetry transformation imply that the action will change by a total derivative of some vector $J^{\mu}$? I know that this is the definition of "the symmetry transformation", but what is the motivation behind this definition? Does the motivation have to do with Taylor expanding the action?
I know I have asked this earlier, but I didn't get an answer.
P.S.: I have this question because I was under the impression that a symmetry is a transformation that does not alter the classical equations of motion. But apparently, this is not the case.

Well, but the EOM don't change if the action changes by a total derivative, no?

No @TobiasFünke, but I think this is not the main motivation...

Sorry, I don't know if I understand your reply. After reading your post scriptum, I thought that this is the motivation you are looking for. And as far as I know, a transformation which changes the action indeed is a symmetry of the EOM, roughly speaking. See e.g. this. But perhaps I am just misinterpreting your answer? Or I am missing some things here.

I think I am having difficulty understanding what is the fundamental reason for us to call a symmetry transformation the transformation that leaves the action unchanged (up to boundary terms)

Apart from the fact that Noether's first theorem not only works for strict symmetries but also for quasisymmetries of an action $S_V$ (say, in some spacetime region $V$), one intuitive reason to only require that $S_V$ respects the symmetry modulo boundary terms is that if the model has a (horizontal) spacetime symmetry vector field $X=X^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$, there generically will be a flux in or out of $V$ at the boundary $\partial V$ that breaks the strict symmetry.
Similarly, symmetry transformations are not required to respect boundary conditions, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.

So, the point is that $S_V$ is unchanged by the symmetry transformation inside $V$ and only inside $V$. So, up to boundary contributions (that may not be zero, but if they are, then the symmetry is a quasisymmetry), $S_V$ is unchanged and that, $S_V$ being unchanged, is the true meaning of (quasi-)symmetry. Is this correct?
